# write method of texture2d<int, access:write> do not work in metal shader function

Tags: ios, macos, shader, gpu, metal

As mentioned in Apple's document, texture2d of shading language could be of int type. I have tried to use texture2d of int type as parameter of shader language, but the write method of texture2d failed to work.

```
kernel void dummy(texture2d<int, access::write> outTexture [[ texture(0) ]],

                               uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{       

     outTexture.write( int4( 2, 4, 6, 8 ), gid );

}
```

However, if I replace the int with float, it worked.

```
kernel void dummy(texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[ texture(0) ]],

                               uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{       

     outTexture.write( float4( 1.0, 0, 0, 1.0 ), gid );

}
```

Could other types of texture2d, such texture2d of int, texture2d of short and so on, be used as shader function parameters, and how to use them? Thanks for reviewing my question.

The related host codes:

```
 MTLTextureDescriptor *desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm 
 desc.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
 id<MTLTexture> texture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:desc];
 [commandEncoder setTexture:texture    atIndex:0];
```

The code to show the output computed by GPU, w and h represents width and height of textrue, respectively.

```
uint8_t* imageBytes = malloc(w*h*4);
memset( imageBytes, 0, w*h*4 );
MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, [texture width], [texture height]);
[texture getBytes:imageBytes bytesPerRow:[texture width]*4 fromRegion:region mipmapLevel:0];

for( int j = 0; j < h; j++ )
{
  printf("%3d: ", j);
  for( int i = 0; i < w*pixel_size; i++ )
  {
       printf(" %3d",imageBytes[j*w*pixel_size+i] );
  }
   printf("\n")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the pixel format you used to create this texture (`MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm`) is **normalized**, meaning that the expected pixel value range is 0.0-1.0. For normalized pixel types, the required data type for reading or writing to this texture within a Metal kernel is float or half-float.

In order to write to a texture with integers, you must select an integer pixel format. Here are all of the available formats:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlpixelformat

Answer (score 0):

The [Metal Shading Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/data-types/data-types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364-CH2-SW12) states that:

> Note: If T is int or short, the data associated with the texture must use a signed integer format. If T is uint or ushort, the data associated with the texture must use an unsigned integer format.

All you have to do is make sure the texture you write to in the API (host code) matches what you have in the kernel function. Alternatively, you can also cast the `int` values into `float` before writing to the `outTexture`.

Comment: @ Marius. Thanks for your response. What does API (host code) match mean? The related host codes was also listed above. Would you please point out if there were any problems?

Comment: before you setTexture make sure your texture data is also int. if you cannot make it work this way, you can also cast the ints to floats before writing to outTexture.